# Running LiftWeb in production

Tags: jetty, lift

I'm new to LiftWeb and was wondering how do I start it in production environment when its hosted in Jetty server.

Thanks,

Gil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package your Lift app in to a war file (e.g. if you're using sbt, use 'sbt package-war'). Suppose it's called MyApp.war

Suppose jetty is installed in /Applications/jetty

Copy the MyApp.war file into the /Applications/jetty/webapps

cd to /Applications/jetty

java -Drun.mode=production -jar start.jar etc/jetty.xml

Your app will be available at http://localhost:8080/MyApp (although check your jetty.xml file to confirm which port the connector is listening on)